# showing error message in php

Tags: php

want to show a error message as a result of a form action. For example

```
<form action=a.php
      input .....
</form>
<span.....>
<?php 
    $variable(Initially the value of this variable null according to the result of form value will change)
?>
</span>
```

For a specific condition I want to set a value of $variable in a.php page and  return to form page using `header();` . But `$variable` does not change. How can I change $variable from a.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SESSION variables.

in the head of each document put
`session_start();`

after this you assign the variables you nedd to access across document like this: `$_SESSION['variable'];`

Define the session variable right before using header(); then insert something like:

`if (isset($_SESSION['variable'])){ 
     print $_SESSION['variable'];
     unset($_SESSION['variable']);
}`

Answer (score 2):

PHP variables are not persistent, when you redirect the browser to another location, your script's execution is terminated and you lose all of your variables and their values. Read about [session handling](http://bg.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) in the PHP documentation for a way to store persistent data between requests.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not quite clear, but sounds like you need this:

```
if(isset($variable) AND $variable != '') echo "<span>$variable</span>";
```